# Error in defining interface for given object

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to create interface in Angular app, I have following object structure

```
 productGroups: IProduct[] = 
 [
    {
      num:1,
      productlist:[
        {
          letter:"A",
          products:[
            'Aprod1',
            'Aprod2'
          ]
        },
        {
          letter:"B",
          products:[
            'Bprod3',
            'Bprod4'
          ]
        }
      ]        
    },

    {
      num:2,
      productlist:[
        {
          letter:"A",
          products:[
            'prod1',
            'prod2'
          ]
        }
      ]        
    } 
  ]
```

what I tried is

```
export interface IProduct {
 num : number;
 letter : string;
 products : string[];
 productlist : any[];//comprise array of letter and products
}
```

Have I defined interface correctly??? I am getting error 
{
    "owner": "typescript",
    "code": "2739",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "Type '{ num: string; productlist: { letter: string; products: string[]; }[]; }' is 
                missing the following properties from type 'Product': letter, products",
}

Comment: where is your interface `Product` your interface below is named as `IProduct`?

Comment: both answers are correct

Comment: sorry Arvind I updated question, interface is IProduct

Comment: did any of the below answers helped you?

Answer (score 1):

Your interface has a flatter structure than your objects ('letter' property is nested inside `products` in example objects, but right on the top level in the interface definition). It's more something like this:

```
interface IProductListEntry {
    letter: string;
    products: string[]; 
}

interface IProduct {
    num : number;
    productlist : IProductListEntry[];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your ProductList interface is wrong because your productlist is not a `string[]`, the following should work

```
export interface IProduct {
 num : number;
 productlist : IProductList[];
}

export interface IProductList {
 letter : string;
 products : string[];
}
```